# Hide table column, which applied colspan...?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I read lots question but no match for my situation.
Here is my table structure

[image]

If I want to hide column **A** or **B** below code work for me.

```
$('table td:nth-child(1),table th:nth-child(1)').hide();
$('table td:nth-child(2),table th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

But if I want to remove **C** or later column it create problem for me.
like below code gave me non-relavent output.

```
$('table td:nth-child(3),table th:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

[image]

Please find fiddle for this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/96A9C/)

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Of course. You're removing the 3rd child - on the middle column you need to also remove the 4th child.

Comment: for 3rd you need to hide 4th too

Comment: If you know which columns you need to hide, how about adding specific CSS classes to the to-be-hidden columns and showing/hiding these using `$('.toggle-column1').toggle();`?

Comment: See example fiddle with two toggleable column groups (just updated): http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/g2rym/1/

Comment: sascham78, good one, but expecting pure jquey answer without adding any class

Answer (score 4):

## Pure CSS

This can be done with CSS using the [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) and [`+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) selectors:

```css
tr :nth-child(3),
tr :nth-child(3):not([colspan]) + :nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/8Q3uN/1).

What this does is hide the 3rd child, then hide the element preceding the 3rd child which has no `colspan` property.

In your table, this will hide cells with content `C`, `3` and `4`.

### Update

As BoltClock [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008618/hide-table-column-which-applied-colspan/22008909?noredirect=1#comment33377481_22008909), the above CSS would target any `:nth-child(n)` found within the `tr`. To ensure this only targets `td` or `th` elements, we can introduce the child combinator (`>`):

```css
tr > :nth-child(3),
tr > :nth-child(3):not([colspan]) + :nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
}
```

You'll want to use this if your `td` or `th` elements contain children of their own.

## jQuery

With jQuery you can loop through each `tr` element, determining whether the first row's matching `th` element has a `colspan` property, then processing accordingly. Here I've wrapped this in a function called `hideColumn()` which accepts an *n* argument relating to the column you wish to hide:

```
$(function() {
    function hideColumn(n) {
        var headerColSpan = 1;

        $('tr').each(function(i) {
            var nth = $(this).children()[n-1],
                colspan = $(nth).attr('colspan');

            // Pull ColSpan from first row th element
            if (i === 0)
                headerColspan = colspan || 1;

            if (colspan === headerColspan)
                $(nth).hide();
            else
                for (i=0; i < headerColspan; i++) {
                    $($(this).children()[n-1+i]).hide();
                }
        });
    }

    hideColumn(3);
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/8Q3uN/3/).

Comment: Good one, but can u guide me how to apply same using jquery.

Comment: @Deer I've added a jQuery solution to my answer.

Comment: Expecting some neat jquery for this, but I think have to write this much lines of code. Thanks

Comment: it will not work for hideColumn(5); etc. have any update let me know.

Comment: @Deer your requirements are varying greatly from what you originally asked. My original CSS solution answers the question you originally asked.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I assume people will got that I need this thing for all related columns, because in question I just give one example what I require. Thanks for your suggestion, but hope now u got what I want.Hope you can do something with your code to solve this.

Comment: If the universal `:nth-child()` selector is intended to match only `td, th` elements it would be a good idea to prepend the `>` combinator so you don't inadvertently pick up any further descendants within the `td, th` elements.

Comment: BoltClock can you do some fiddle for your comment

Comment: @Deer what BoltClock means is that any `:nth-child(n)` found within the `tr` element would be targeted. I've updated my answer to avoid this.